# Django autocomplete light queryset filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-autocomplete-light

models

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(GuestContact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class GuestContact(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=30)
    contact_genere_id = models.ForeignKey(ContactGenere, on_delete=models.PROTECT) # 1 = company 2 = guest
```

form

```
class ReservationForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'company': autocomplete.ModelSelect2()
    }
```

views

```
class GuestContactAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
def get_queryset(self):

    qs = GuestContact.objects.filter(contact_genere_id=1)

    return qs
```

this QuerySet filter works in python shell, in my views this not work i see all contacts not only company contacts. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need an url for you view:
something like this:

```
from .views import GuestContactAutocomplete

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^guest-contact-autocomplete/$',
        GuestContactAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='guest-contact-autocomplete'
    ),
]
```

To then in the form, set this url name to the form field widget, like this:

```
class ReservationForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'company': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='guest-contact-autocomplete')
}
```